# Running primary and secondary DPDK applications in different K8s pods

Tags: kubernetes, dpdk

I'm new to DPDK. My current goal is to create an app that will be using DPDK with K8s.
The app must have a way to communicate between different pods on a same node in a fast way via IPC/Hugepages https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/multi_proc_support.html#memory-sharing (not K8s/microservices way, but it is what it is).
And when it comes to K8s, there are some errors i'm encountering.

The obvious solution to that would be to have two containers on one Pod, but there is a requirement to do it in different Pods for a better scalability, even with a restriction on having them scaled on one Node only.

I wrote two DPDK applications that will be running together (primary and secondary).
They are just putting(primary) and reading(secondary) data from a ring.

Primary:

```
struct rte_ring *ring;
ring = rte_ring_create("SEND_RING", 128, socket, 0);//RING_F_SP_ENQ | RING_F_SC_DEQ);
if (!ring){
    rte_log(RTE_LOGTYPE_EAL, RTE_LOG_ERR, "Ring creation error");
}
///
void *msg = NULL;
rte_mempool_get(mempool, &msg);
strlcpy((char*)msg, "some", 5);
if (rte_ring_enqueue_burst(ring, &msg, 1, NULL) < 0){
    rte_log(RTE_LOGTYPE_EAL, RTE_LOG_ERR, "Enqueue error");
}
```

Secondary:

```
struct rte_mempool *mempool = rte_mempool_lookup("DPDK_mbuf_pool_TX");
struct rte_ring *ring = rte_ring_lookup("SEND_RING");
if (!ring || !mempool){
    rte_log(RTE_LOGTYPE_EAL, RTE_LOG_ERR, "ring or mempool were not found!");
    rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "ring or mempool were not found");
}

void *msg = NULL;
if (rte_ring_dequeue_burst(ring, &msg, 1, NULL) < 0) {
    rte_log(RTE_LOGTYPE_EAL, RTE_LOG_ERR, "Dequeue didn't work\n");
} else {
    rte_log(RTE_LOGTYPE_EAL, RTE_LOG_INFO, "Got message #%d: %s\n", ack_msgs++, (char *) msg);
    rte_mempool_put(mempool, msg);
}
```

Initially, i set up a host machine by binding one of the interfaces to DPDK and setting up hugepages.

I've tested it on my host machine when running two apps as separate processes - they work. Data is put on a ring in the first application, and second application started with `--proc-type=secondary` works and gets data from the ring.

I've tested it on two separate docker containers running with privileged mode and volumes mounted to them. They work perfectly too.

```
docker create -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules -v /dev/hugepages:/dev/hugepages --privileged --net=host -v /var/run/dpdk:/var/run/dpdk --name adder adder:latest
docker create -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules -v /dev/hugepages:/dev/hugepages --privileged --net=host -v /var/run/dpdk:/var/run/dpdk --name getter getter:latest
```

Now i'm trying to recreate the same on the K8s (using minikube with driver=none, (driver=docker too, same)), but i'm getting this error all the time.

```
root@getter:/build# ./bare_dpdk --proc-type=secondary
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected shared linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket_19_3ae64b90ef5
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Error allocating from heap
EAL: error allocating rte services array
EAL: FATAL: rte_service_init() failed
EAL: rte_service_init() failed
Port 0 is invalid (out of range or not attached)
```

With additional logs:

```
EAL: sendmsg: mp_malloc_request
EAL: msg: mp_malloc_sync
EAL: reply: mp_malloc_sync
EAL: msg: mp_malloc_response
EAL: Error allocating from heap
EAL: error allocating rte services array
```

Content of yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: adder
  labels:
    app: "adder"
spec:
  #  hostIPC: true
  #  hostNetwork: true
  #  hostPID: true
  containers:
    - name: "adder"
      image: adder
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      volumeMounts:
        - name: modules
          mountPath: /lib/modules
        - name: hugepage
          mountPath: /dev/hugepages
        - name: dpdk
          mountPath: /var/run/dpdk
      resources:
        limits:
          hugepages-2Mi: 100Mi
          memory: 500Mi
        requests:
          memory: 500Mi
  volumes:
    - name: modules
      hostPath:
        path: /lib/modules
    - name: dpdk
      hostPath:
        path: /var/run/dpdk
    - name: hugepage
      emptyDir:
        medium: HugePages
```

And i have no idea what to do. I feel it might be something with a way how hugepages are done in K8s, or some additional layering that's blocking it, but i don't have a clue what to do with that.
I would be happy to answer any questions and provide additional data/logs if needed. Thanks in advance! :)

According to the code of DPDK, this error happens here:

```
        if (!alloc_more_mem_on_socket(heap, size, socket_id, flags, align,
                        bound, contig)) {
                ret = heap_alloc(heap, type, size, flags, align, bound,
contig);

                /* this should have succeeded */
                if (ret == NULL)
                        RTE_LOG(ERR, EAL, "Error allocating from heap\n");
        }
```

https://inbox.dpdk.org/dev/bug-378-3@http.bugs.dpdk.org%2F/T/